# how to link with an extra object file?

Tags: visual-c++

I have a visual c++ project which compiled correctly. Myproject.vcxproj contains a1.cpp, a2.cpp.
Now I'd like to remove a1.cpp from the project and link with the previously generated a1.obj .

I have added $(SolutionDir) to VC++/Library directories
I have added a1.obj to Linker/Input/Additional dependencies

I have got the following error message
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'a1.obj'

What I made wrong?
I'm using Visual C++ Express 2010.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Why not make a library from the original files and use the `.lib` as an input. Also, surely the .obj file isn't in the Solution directory - there will be one debug version and one release version. And if you want to upgrade to a newer compiler you can't use a previously generated obj file. This is madness.

Comment: I tried to make a library but I have got similar error message. So at first I will try this. I'm trying to make the main app as a Debug version so probably $(SolutionDir) is the same. I'd tried to add the real path (not with macros) to Library directories but the error message is the same.

Comment: doctorlove: Please don't answer the questions with more questions. Answer the question, or don't answer it. Don't change the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A (relatively) clean way to do what you seem to be trying to do is to make a library in the same solution, and add it as a reference to the project that will use it.

Right click the project, select "References" then "Add new reference" and then select the library project in your solution.

If you really want to try using the linker properties, note that there is a "Additional Libraries Directory" setting - this will need to be the `OutputDir` of the project you are trying to import - and is different to the "Additional dependencies" library name (just the lib name without a path)